# xhr.upload.addEventListener "loadend" is not working in safari

Tags: xmlhttprequest

```
xhr.upload.addEventListener('loadend', function(e) {

});
```

I use this when the upload is complete I want to do some operatiojn but it is not fire in safari. any help please.

Answer (score 0):

try  to set it as a function like this:

```
 upload.onloadend = function(){

 }
```